# Can I create an .ipa file from a Mac VM using xcode, for free?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, provisioning-profile, ipa

So I created a Mac virtual machine(10.14.3 Mojave) using VMware and I installed Xcode. After I finished my app, I wanted to create an IPA file so as to send it to ppl to test it. I searched over the internet and found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gRp5Z0tpXM&t=178s). I followed the tutorial in detail, with Xcode 10 and 9 with no result.

[image]

[image]

Do you have any suggestions? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The error says that Xcode was unable to log in using the Apple ID credentials supplied. Check the account settings in Xcode preferences. Is that Apple ID a member of the Apple developer program?  You will need to add the UDID of your test device to the provisioning profile in the developer portal if it isn't connected to the VM via USB. I believe with a free membership you are limited to one UDID so others won't be able to run your app.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I'll join the apple dev program and follow the steps mentioned above.